# Center vertically a div with variable height and display:none property

Tags: css, center, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to center a div inside another one. The div has variable height, because it may contain shorter or longer text. Also, since the div is a modal window, in css it has the property display: none so I can't use display: table-cell (I think?). Here are the property of the two divs:

```
#page {
height: 100vh;}

.white_content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 36%;
width: 28%;
height: auto;
padding: 16px;
background-color: #ffffff;
z-index: 1002;
overflow: auto;}
```

There's my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c11a41bz/).

Comment: Which element are you talking about? What is the point of centering an element with `display: none`, if you won't see it?

Comment: I want to center the div with the class .white_content. You can see it when you open the modal dialog.

Comment: You want to center `.white_content` relatively to what?

Comment: To the div with id #page. I know the width of .white_content, so I have no problems centering it horizontally.

Comment: _“Also, since the div is a modal window, in css it has the property display: none so I can't use display: table-cell”_ – that makes no sense whatsoever. As long as it is not visible at all, there is not need to center it. And to _make_ it visible, you need to replace `display:none` with something else anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the `.white_content` to this it center vertically

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/c11a41bz/3/)

```
.white_content {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 36%;
    width: 28%;
    height: auto;
    top: 50%;
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 1002;
    overflow: auto;
    transform: translateY(-50%): 
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it's always visible. I wanted it to be visible only when clicking on the link.

Comment: @nadiaeagle Yeah, but I just added that to show it in place, just change back to `display:none`

Comment: Ok, I understood that! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you are using CSS rule

```
.white_content{
 position:relative
 top:20%
}
```

use

```
top:50%;
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uLuvcsfb/)

Comment: This (http://oi63.tinypic.com/2j5e4xz.jpg) happens if I use top: 50%;
I didn't write all the code in the JSFiddle, so it could be easier to understand.